# How to set variable for all theme templates in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-templates, drupal-preprocess

I want to set few global variables which I need to be available in all my theme's Twig templates in Drupal 8.

[Drupal 7 documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430) mentions preprocess function:

> themeName_preprocess
>   This one is named after the theme itself. Applies to all hooks.

So I added the function below to my `themename.theme` file, but the variables aren't set.

```
function themename_preprocess(&$variables) {
  $theme_path = $variables['base_path'] . $variables['directory'];
  $variables['theme_path'] = $theme_path;
  $variables['images_path'] = $theme_path . "/images/";
  $variables['templates_path'] = $theme_path . "/templates/";
}
```

When instead of defining `themename_preprocess` I define `themename_preprocess_page` (below) the variables are properly defined and available in `page.html.twig` template.

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $theme_path = $variables['base_path'] . $variables['directory'];
  $variables['theme_path'] = $theme_path;
  $variables['images_path'] = $theme_path . "/images/";
  $variables['templates_path'] = $theme_path . "/templates/";
}
```

But I want the variables to be available in **all** templates instead of only `page.html.twig`. How can I do that?

Comment: It turned out the solution was to simply rebuild the cache. It's only weird and misleading that defining and changing `themename_preprocess_page()` was working without rebuilding the cache.

Answer (score 1):

```
function themename_preprocess(&$variables) {
    // code
}
```

Did the trick for me after a cache clear.